# Backward Modulo/Reminder Cycle

Tags: python, loops, math, cycle, modulo

Using Python as an example:

```
for i in range(-5, 5, 1):
    print(i % 4, end = " ") ## Will output 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3...
```

Is there a nice way do get a reverse cycle with decreasing input including negative numbers? How would I get the following without using conditions?

```
for i in range(5, -5 , -1):
    print('''Something here''', end = " ") ## Will output 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with this simple offset shift:

```
for i in range(5, -5 , -1):
    print((i+2)%4, end = " ")
```

outputs:

```
3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 2
```

Comment: I just realized that I have a different problem